# I have found that just before the </head> tag I have <script id="__isTpiViewExists"></script>. Is this a virus?

Tags: javascript, html, virus

In the HTML code just before the `</head>` tag I have this:

```
<script id="__isTpiViewExists"></script>
```

I never put it there. Is it possible to be a virus or something else?

Edit //

By using google chrome debugging tool in the Scripts section i have everypage_early.js // This content script get injected into every page, enabling us to inject the conduit commmunity toolbar into the DOM of the page.

Another note : In Firefox using firebug i dont have this script only when I use google chrome debugging tool,also if I right click and View Page Source.I dont have the script only in google chrome debugging tool.. so i think is not a virus just google add in there tool .. i dont know

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party scripts?

Comment: We need more details: who is your web host? Did you contact their support already?

Comment: google analytics and jquery.min scripts.By using google chrome debugging tool in the Scripts section i have everypage_early.js // This content script get injected into every page, enabling us to inject the conduit commmunity toolbar into the DOM of the page.

Comment: And if you block these scripts, does the script tag go away? Are you seeing it on more than one browser? If not disable plug-ins and see if they are adding it.

Comment: so wouldnt that make that script tag the placeholder for it?

Comment: I open http://stackoverflow.com and hit F12 for google chrome debugging tool and I see the same thing. The only 3rd party app i have installed is utorrent toolbar

Answer (score 0):

This is the nasty nasty conduit toolbar which injects javascript into every page it visits in order to hjiack the behvaiour. If you see this, run MalwareBytes and another AV and uninstall all toolbars and update your system.